# Packaging of SOAP Services

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soa, packaging

I deployed all my previous SOAP Services using `WAR` file format.

Is it possible to package SOAP Services in an `EAR`- or `JAR`-File???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when we create our webservice using jdev and compile that service it will automatically create jar which we have to deploy on em console.through console we can check instance of that service and check of audit flow.

Answer (score 2):

EAR packages WARs, common JARs and EJB JARs. So if you put your services into WAR which is in EAR it will work. Other options depend on your publication mechanisms. Basically if class is on application classpath it can be published so. It should not matter where the class is.

Comment: And what if I pack my SOAP Services directly into EAR or JAR? Or isnt it possible to pack something directly into an EAR? Sorry, I dont know much about packaging ;-)

Comment: If you simply copy your classes into ear dir it won't work. You have to put them into ear/lib if they should be common for ejb's and wars, or inside a war/web-inf/lib. The trick is that your publishing point should have access to those classes. It depends on classloader type used in yor application server.